# Install gdal2tiles inside conda environment

Tags: python, gdal, gdal2tiles, anaconda

I need to use gdal2tiles with Anaconda 3 on Ubuntu 18.04. I've created the environment using:

> conda create --name gisenv python=3.6

I've installed GDAL with:

> conda install gdal

After this I've created a simple python script `import gdal2tiles` but I see this error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal2tiles'

I thought that using *conda install gdal2tiles* would solve the problem but I see this message:

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving
>   environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible
>   solve. Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving
>   environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible
>   solve.
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
>   current channels:
>
> - gdal2tiles
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
>   you're looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

How I can solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python module `gdal2tiles` is not in the path by default

I'm able to import it using

```
conda create --name gisenv python=3.6
conda activate gisenv
conda install gdal
```

Then, running the following in python does work

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'], 'bin'))
import gdal2tiles
```

I'm surprised you don't use the command line `gdal2tiles.py` instead of trying to run it through Python. Curious about your use case.

Comment: I'm learning python I preferred to share only the first line of a script inside a .py that use also gdal2tiles.

Answer (score 0):

After installing gdal 3.7.0 from the conda-forge channel, I was able to do the same thing without needing to do any `sys.path` manipulations. Simply:

```py
from osgeo_utils.gdal2tiles import main
```